# ssh-copy-id doesn't copy to non-default location

Tags: shell, login, authentication, openssh

Does ssh-copy-id recognize if the authorized_keys file is not in ~/.ssh? I am storing my authorized keys file in a different folder, which I have configured as:

AuthorizedKeysFile  /mnt/sd_ext/.ssh/authorized_keys

But running ssh-copy-id on a client machine still causes the file to be created in ~/.ssh. Am I missing something, or is this expected behavior?

Comment: Another way to configure ssh is to symlink: `cd .ssh; ln -st . /mnt/sd_ext/.ssh/authorized_keys` This will work for all applications, as it is the file-system/operating-system that does the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ssh-copy-id` is actually a shell script as can be seen:

```
$ which ssh-copy-id
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id

$ file /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

It’s a fairly simple script and the `.ssh/authorized_keys` path is hard-coded as the script isn’t written to deal with non-standard locations for the `authorized_keys` file, i.e., it will always copy the keys into `authorized_keys` in `~/.ssh`.

Sticking to convention is usually best practice but if you have a good reason for using a non-standard path, you can try editing the script to replace `.ssh/authorized_keys` with your own custom location.

Comment: Couldn't ask for a better answer, really.

Comment: @nrcrast Glad to have helped. Welcome to Unix & Linux SE!